# How to migrate from using Flask-JWT to PyJWT in my app?

Tags: python, flask, jwt, pyjwt

I want to switch from using Flask-JWT since it is no longer being updated. My problem is that I'm not sure how to achieve some of the functionality that Flask-JWT was giving me. For example:

`jwt = JWT(app, verify, identify)`

With Flask-JWT i could pass the flask app, authentication method and a `identify` function that does he following:

```
def identify(payload):
    user_id = payload['identity']
    return {"user_id": user_id}
```

Now my main problem is that I do not fully understand what the decorator `@jwt_required()` does and how I could replicate it using PyJWT. So if I had the following function:

```
class PrivateResource(Resource):
    @jwt_required()

    def get(self):
        return {"badge_number": 445566}
```

How could I do the same function as `@jwt_required()` while using PyJWT?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check out flask jwt extended. It is a better designed flask jwt extension (IMO) that is still actively maintained. http://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/latest/